# Save Array with FOR cycle

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Good morning, I am trying to save the quantities generated by the FOR cycle.
We enter the initial number and the final number and the result is the range of numbers that we select.
Example:
Initial Number Final Number
fifteen

```
Result: 1 2 3 4 5.
```

My question is how do I save my result [1 2 3 4 5] in the database.
In such a way that when you enter the initial and final number the numbers 12345 are saved in BD.

BD:

```
Id Series
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

Code:

```
<?php

//Start of the connection
include("Connection.php");

/*******************************************************************************
* INSERT DATA
*******************************************************************************/
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
  $Series = $_POST['Series'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO test (`Series`)
    VALUES('$Series' )";
      $mysqli->query($query);

      printf ("New record with the id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
    }
    ?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="modal fade modal-mini modal-primary" id="modal_combu_bitagas" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST"  class="form-horizontal">
                      <div class="row">
                        <input type="text" name="ninitial" id="ninitial" placeholder="initial value"/>
                        <input type="text" name="nend" placeholder="final value" />
                          <?php
                          $quantity = (int)$_POST['ninitial'];
                          $quantityfinal = (int)$_POST['nend'];
                          for($quantity=$quantity; $quantity <= $quantityfinal; $quantity++)
                          {
                          ?>
                          <input type="text" name="Series" id="Series" value="<?php echo $quantity ?>" >
                          <?php
                          }
                           ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" vale="Submit" />
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you do `$quantity = $quantity`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but `INSERT INTO test (Series) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)`

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't use `id="Series"` in a loop.

Comment: Is the user supposed to change the values in the input? Do you want to save the original values or the updated elements?

Comment: You should use `name="Series[]"`. Then when the form is submitted, `$_POST['Series']` will be an array of all the inputs. You can use a loop to insert these into the DB.

Comment: What I want si to enter the initial number and final number. Example initial number =1 Final number = 5. It is printed 1 2 3 4 5. These number (1 2 3 4 5 ) are the ones that I want to be inserted in the Database.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to separate php and html code.

In html:

> 1. input ninitial and nend
> 2. (if need show numbers before insert) use javascript FOR cycle generate and show result numbers.
> 3. send http request, post ninitial and nend to php
> 4. (if need show numbers after insert) check the response, and show the result.

In php:

> 1. get ninitial and nend by $_POST.
> 2. use php For cycle generate result numbers.
> 3. insert numbers in DB.
> 4. response inserted info to FrontEnd.

PHP code:

```
include("Connection.php");

$numbers = array();

$startNumber = $_POST["ninitial"];
$endNumber = $_POST["nend"];

for($i = $startNumber; $i <= $endNumber; $i++){
    if(insertNumber($mysqli, $i)){
        $numbers[$mysqli->insert_id] = $i;
    }
}
//response $numbers if need


function insertData($mysqli, $number){
    $query = "INSERT INTO test (`Series`) VALUES ($number)";
    return $mysqli->query($query);
}
```